# MySQL second maximums of each user

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL table there are two columns: user and score.

How can I get a table with the second maximum scores of each user? And the maximum of these second maximums?

In other words, I could have this table:

```
User | Score
X      50
Y      74
X      9
X      12
Y      21
```

I want to get a table with the second maximums:

```
User | Score
X    | 12
Y    | 21
```

And another one with the maximum of the second maximums:

```
Score
21
```

Note: Performance is important. I will consider as correct the fastest solution.

Comment: Please define `second maximum score` better.

Comment: I tried to combined LIMIT 1,1 and GROUP BY. But It doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scores;

CREATE TABLE scores(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,user CHAR(1) NOT NULL,score INT NOT NULL,INDEX(user,score));

INSERT INTO scores (user,score)
VALUES 
('X',50),
('Y',74),
('X',9),
('X',12),
('Y',21);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM scores x 
  JOIN scores y 
    ON y.user = x.user 
   AND y.score >= x.score 
 GROUP 
    BY x.user
     , x.score 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
 ORDER 
    BY score DESC 
 LIMIT 1;

+----+------+-------+
| id | user | score |
+----+------+-------+
|  5 | Y    |    21 |
+----+------+-------+
```

If there's a chance that the same user could have the same score twice, then you may need to include a DISTINCT in there somewhere - but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

If performance is an issue then a solution similar to the following is infinitely more scalable. I say 'similar' because I have a habit of becoming muddled when trying to track multiple variables...

```
SELECT id,user,score
  FROM
     (
     SELECT id
     , user
     , score
     , @puser := @cuser
     , @prev := @curr
     , @cuser := user
     , @curr := score
     , @rank := IF(@puser = @cuser,IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1),@rank:=1) rank
  FROM scores
  JOIN (SELECT @cuser :=null,@puser := null,@curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) sel1
 ORDER 
    BY user, score DESC
    ) x
  WHERE rank = 2
  ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1;

+----+------+-------+
| id | user | score |
+----+------+-------+
|  5 | Y    |    21 |
+----+------+-------+
```

A quick test on an indexed table of two users and ca. 10,000 rows. Query 1 completes in 15 seconds, while query 2 completes in 1/100th of a second!

Comment: If I understand correctly your query, it uses a table with dimensions number_of_scores * number_of_scores. Then it isn't a good solution for large tables.

Comment: Large means that after 30 seconds calculating I stopped the query in my database.

Comment: I have another column as id.

Comment: It works and is fast. The only problem is that I don't understand what it does ;-)

Comment: Basically, it parses the data set according to a defined ORDER and then increments a variable (@rank) according to a set of rules. The other variables help enforce those rules.

Answer (score 0):

**All the entries without the `MAX` for each user:**

```
SELECT t1.user, t1.score FROM t t1, 
    (SELECT t2.user, t2.score FROM t t2 WHERE t2.score = 
        (SELECT MAX(t3.score) FROM t t3 WHERE t2.user = t3.user)) t4 
WHERE t1.user = t4.user AND t1.score <> t4.score 
GROUP BY t1.user DESC ORDER BY t1.user, t1.score;
```

**Only `MAX` of second maximums:**

```
SELECT t1.user, MAX(t1.score) FROM t t1, 
    (SELECT t2.user, t2.score FROM t t2 WHERE t2.score = 
        (SELECT MAX(t3.score) FROM t t3 WHERE t2.user = t3.user)) t4 
WHERE t1.user = t4.user AND t1.score <> t4.score;
```

***SQLFiddle:*** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e717/29

Comment: I want the second max of EACH user.

Comment: But this query give me some ideas.

Comment: Maybe if you give us the description of the table and some example data, we could help you.

Comment: Check now, @Medicalphysicist

Answer (score 0):

this will give you second highest score:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `score` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

note: and it very much helpfull for us if you give a clean picture of your table .